# Visual Studio - Publish vs Publish Wizard

Tags: visual-studio, publish

What are some of the main differences between `Publish Now` and `Publish Wizard` within Visual Studio? I've searched online, but I'm still confused on which one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013 the Publish Wizard is generally for the first time you publish an application, it will walk you through selecting the location your program will publish to, how the application will be installed by users (from a webpage, file-share, or cd/dvd/file location.), and if your program will check for updates.  
The Publish Now option will take all the settings you entered in the Publish Wizard or the default settings if you haven't set them and publish the program. 
 So you will usually want to go through the Publish Wizard the first time you publish, then subsequent publications can be done using Publish Now.